# Is the ddd() helper not working in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel-9

I upgraded to Laravel 9 the other day, and now the `ddd()` helper is failing with the error `Call to undefined function ddd()`. I found [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/ddd-helper-is-not-working-on-laravel-9) on the Laracasts forum, but at time of writing there is only a single reply that states that the `facade/ignition` was replaced with `spatie/laravel-ignition`. I did not see anything in the documentation for the new package that mentions anything changing with `ddd()`, is there an additional configuration or something that is needed to re-enable `ddd()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `spatie/laravel-ignition` version 1.2.0, `ddd()` was added back in! If you are not able to use `ddd()`, first check your `composer.json` file to make sure that your `spatie/laravel-ignition` version is 1.2.0 or above.

```
"require-dev": {
    "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.2.3"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this https://github.com/facade/ignition/pull/201#event-2712168617

> jasonvarga deleted the ddd branch 2 years ago

And you are right about not seeing any documentation about it in changelogs as well.

I heard this `ddd()` helper for the first time from you, so thax for that.
Please do check out the documentation of both of the packages.
Here  [facade / ignition](https://github.com/facade/ignition#readme) and  [spatie / laravel-ignition](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-ignition#readme)

Both packages saying the same thing that

> spatie/laravel-ignition works for Laravel 8 and 9 applications running
> on PHP 8.0 and above. Looking for Ignition for Laravel 5.x, 6.x or 7.x
> or old PHP versions? facade/ignition is still compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! [This discussion](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-ignition/discussions/16) on the spatie/laravel-ignition GitHub gives me some hope, so I'll keep this question open for a while and see if a pull-request comes through to put the ```ddd()``` feature back in.

Comment: Also check this out https://github.com/facade/ignition/pull/201#issuecomment-1060759009